could not find driver using laragon
I’m working on an OOP project with Laragon locally. I configured my database using environment variables that I placed in a Constant.php file. I also created a User model to establish the database connection. However, when I try to display my var_dump($user), I get the error “could not find driver.”
Here are my main files:
Constant.php
<?php
namespace Source;

class Constant
{
    public const DB_NAME = 'oop';
    public const DB_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
    public const DB_USERNAME = 'root';
    public const DB_PASSWORD = '';
}

User.php (Model)
<?php
namespace Models;

use Source\Constant;

class User
{
    private static \PDO $pdo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            static::$pdo = new \PDO(
                'mysql:dbname=' . Constant::DB_NAME . ';host=' . Constant::DB_HOST,
                Constant::DB_USERNAME,
                Constant::DB_PASSWORD,
                [
                    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
                    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                ]
            );
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    }

    public function getPDO(): \PDO
    {
        return static::$pdo;
    }
}

Renderer.php
<?php
namespace Source;

class Renderer
{
    public function __construct(private string $viewPath) {}

    public function view()
    {
        ob_start();
        require BASE_VIEW_PATH . $this->viewPath . '.php';
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    public static function make(string $viewPath): static
    {
        return new static($viewPath);
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->view();
    }
}

HomeController.php
<?php
namespace Controllers;

use Models\User;
use Source\Renderer;

class HomeController
{
    public function index(): Renderer
    {
        $userModel = new User();
        $statement = $userModel->getPDO()->query('SELECT * FROM users');

        foreach ($statement->fetchAll() as $user) {
            var_dump($user);
        }

        return Renderer::make('home/index');
    }
}

I’ve already checked that the PHP extensions pdo_mysql, pdo_sqlite, mysqli, and sqlite3 are enabled in PHP -> Extensions. I also verified that my environment variables in Constant.php are correct, and I checked my php.ini file to ensure these extensions are indeed enabled there as well.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Hey El, what version of PHP do you have installed locally?

Hello Marcelo, i am using the 8.1 version

Have you tried with "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1"?

Make sure that the following modules are up and running: php8.1-mysql php8.1-xml php8.1-curl php8.1-gd php8.1-intl

I’ve checked these extensions in my php.ini file, and they are all enabled. and yes i had tried to use localhost instead of  127.0.0.1 but it changes anything !

the problem is probably related to the Mysql version you are using, try to install the latest version of Mysql and PHP8.3, just from a version to another is very easy with Laragon.

Yes thank's @MarcelloPerri, i will do that right now!

@MarcelloPerri I just switched to the latest version of PHP, and I'm still encountering the same error. Could not found driver

what version of mysql do you have locally?

The 8.0 version

I would update mysql as well, The latest is 8.4.3: Released on September 16, 2024

Alright, I’ll do it right away.

I just downloaded the latest version of MySQL, and it's still not working.

I don't know what to say anymore, try to run phpinfo() somewhere in the code and be sure that the required modules are installed.

phpinfo was one of the first things I checked when I encountered the error, and there’s nothing unusual in the configuration.

@MarcelloPerri Could you upvote the question so other developers can see it as a priority?

try to run PDO::getAvailableDrivers to see what drivers are available in your local environment, here is the doc: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.getavailabledrivers.php
print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());

Yes, i will do that right away, thank's !

I tested it, and the drivers are indeed enabled, driver mysql
